# Using slash in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using mysql with php Yii framework.When doing data modelling I came accross some doubt.I have a table for user details like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `company_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `contact_no` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=98 ;
```

Here my problem is I want the state,country should be like this so that I can use the fields like `state/city`

```
 `state/city` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state/province` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

So is it safe to use like this or I have to use only one option there?Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

Comment: Are you asking "is it valid to have `/` in a field name?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's valid.  But you will always need to quote it with backticks.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html for full details on what's allowed.

Comment: in this link it is written as `Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names`.So how to write `city/town` in the database

Comment: @newuser: That was in the old link (for version 4.1).  But either way, you're talking about column names, not table names.